# Is there a way to ensure the Spring Cloud Stream Source has completed initialization?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I am facing a wierd issue with Spring Cloud Stream apps, after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1.4 + Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR1 where my app running in docker on a build server does not seem to be initializing the Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ Binders.

The exception that is thrown is:

```
Failed to call access method: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'myoutput-1.output'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers,
```

The problem is not reproducible locally in a docker run where the app is starting up. We see this in multiple apps we have had that we are migrating over to the Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR1 train.

Any idea on how to trigger the binding explicitly or to listen for binding completion?

Comment: Sounds like you produce messages from your source too early. Would be great to see that code. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to replicate the problem in a way i can share source. When you mention too early? How can I wait or rather what do i wait for @ArtemBilan?

Comment: The source must start producing exactly in the `start()` method of the `SmartLifecycle` implementation. And the `phase` must be like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so your source is started as late as possible. Typically sources are supplied with the `@InboundChannelAdapter` and some trigger configuration, so application context will take care about the proper lifecycle control.